# Refract grease pencil object?

Tags: grease-pencil, eevee-render-engine, glass, 2d

so I'm trying to use the new 2.8 Update to do a grease pencil animation behind a dirty glass window in Eevee, but the grease pencil object does not get refracted or effected at all by the glass shader, it instead renders as if it is in front.

[image: So here is my grease pencil object behind a Principled BSDF glass material with some textures effecting the roughness and specularity.]
So here is my grease pencil object behind a Principled BSDF glass material with some textures effecting the roughness and specularity. It appears to not get tinted or effected by the glass' refraction the way you would expect it to.

For comparison, here is an image applied as a texture to a plane, and the glass' refraction and roughness does smudge and effect the image the way I would want the grease pencil object to.

[image: Image texture on a plane using Alpha Clip mode]

As a side note, I did find that setting the plane's material blend mode to **"Alpha Blend"** instead of **"Alpha Clip"** or **"Alpha Hashed"** results in a similar effect that the grease pencil object had, so maybe it's something to do with the alpha blend mode of grease pencil objects?

[image: Texture using Alpha Blend mode]

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, Grease Pencil is not integrated with Eevee, but this is planned for the future.